# How to merge/left_join multiple data frames based on row names

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following 3 data frames (not tibble):

```r
dat1 <- structure(c(0.033, 0.066, 0.233, 
0.0333333333333333), .Dim = c(2L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(c("A", 
"B"), c("Xxx", "Yyy")))

dat2 <- structure(c(0.1, 0, 0.1, 0.033), .Dim = c(2L, 2L
), .Dimnames = list(c("A", "B"), c("Aaa", "Rrr")))

dat3 <- structure(c(0.2, 0.02, 0.2, 0.03), .Dim = c(2L, 2L
), .Dimnames = list(c("A", "C"), c("Aaa", "Ggg")))

dat1
#>     Xxx        Yyy
#> A 0.033 0.23300000
#> B 0.066 0.03333333
dat2
#>   Aaa   Rrr
#> A 0.1 0.100
#> B 0.0 0.033
dat3
#>    Aaa  Ggg
#> A 0.20 0.20
#> C 0.02 0.03
```

What I want to merge/left_join 3 of them into this final data frame (not tibble):

```r
    Xxx        Yyy    Aaa     Rrr     Aaa.2    Ggg
A 0.033      0.233    0.100  0.100    0.200    0.200
B 0.066      0.033    0.000  0.033    NA       NA
C  NA        NA       NA     NA       0.02     0.03
```

How can I do that?

I tried this but doesn't work:

```r
> l <- list(dat1, dat2, dat3)
> Reduce(merge, lapply(l, function(x) data.frame(x, rn = row.names(x))))
[1] rn  Aaa Xxx Yyy Rrr Ggg
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to specify your join columns in `by`

```
Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, all=TRUE, by="rn", suffixes=c("", ".2")), 
    lapply(list(dat1, dat2, dat3), 
        function(x) data.frame(x, rn = row.names(x))))

#  rn   Xxx        Yyy   Aaa   Rrr Aaa.2  Ggg
#1  A 0.033 0.23300000   0.1 0.100  0.20 0.20
#2  B 0.066 0.03333333   0.0 0.033    NA   NA
#3  C    NA         NA    NA    NA  0.02 0.03
```

Answer (score 4):

We create a column name and then do the join

```
library(tidyverse)
list(dat1, dat2, dat3) %>% 
     map(~ .x %>% 
               as.data.frame %>%
               rownames_to_column('rn')) %>% 
     reduce(full_join, by = 'rn') %>%
     column_to_rownames('rn')
#     Xxx        Yyy Aaa.x   Rrr Aaa.y  Ggg
#A 0.033 0.23300000   0.1 0.100  0.20 0.20
#B 0.066 0.03333333   0.0 0.033    NA   NA
#C    NA         NA    NA    NA  0.02 0.03
```

Comment: @scamander  Please check your package versions as I am not getting the error